# Getting error for POI : org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, data-driven

I have 2 excel files, calling from  TestSuite.xlsx the other TestCase.xlsx file.
My 1st excel file is running successfully but when I run for other excel file getting the following error.

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
at com.iopendr.xls.read.Xls_Reader.<init>(Xls_Reader.java:32)
at com.iopendr.test.DriverScript.start(DriverScript.java:96)
at com.iopendr.test.DriverScript.main(DriverScript.java:60)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:269)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
... 4 more
```

Comment: Is `M1.13` your package name ?

Comment: No, it is not package.

Comment: Where did the problem file come from? Only it's looking like it's not a valid .xlsx file. Can excel open it?

Comment: please check my solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878743/package-should-contain-a-content-type-part-m1-13/35982456#35982456

Comment: @TAYFUNÇELİK I saved excel file save-as then It can read. But in .NET can be read out of save-as.Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

You need to see .xlsx file at column number 13 and verify in your code, I think it takes the another column value instead of 13th column value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(byteFile); //ERROR
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(byteFile); //OK
```

Answer (score 0):

just open the excel sheet in MS Excel and save it in .xlsx format.
then try to access it through the code.

This has worked for me.