# Java : how to parse a doc file (word 97-2003)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I want to parse a **.docx** file, I am doing that :

```
public String parseDOCX(String fileNameorFilePath )
    {
        try {
            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileNameorFilePath));
            XWPFWordExtractor xwpfWordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
            return xwpfWordExtractor.getText();
        }
        catch ( Exception error )
        {
            throw  new RuntimeException(error);
        }
    }
```

When I use this code to parse a **.doc** file(Word 97-2003) I am getting this exception :

> Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException:
>   Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

What would be the best way to open a .doc file?

Comment: Related: [Package should contain a content type part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878743/package-should-contain-a-content-type-part-m1-13/49130309). doc and docx extensions use different classes, like xls and xlsx

Answer (score 2):

According to their [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/components/document/):

> **HWPF** is the name of our port of the Microsoft Word 97(-2007) file format to pure Java. It also provides limited read only support for the older Word 6 and Word 95 file formats.
>
> The partner to HWPF for the new Word 2007 .docx format is XWPF. Whilst HWPF and XWPF provide similar features, there is not a common interface across the two of them at this time.

In other words: nothing in your code should say `XWPFDocument`, you need to use the corresponding interfaces classes built for HWPF.

Comment: Using HWPF : HWPFDocument docx = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileNameorFilePath));  I am getting this error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument: method <init>()V not found
 at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:144)
 at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:133)

Comment: Remove the older Apache POI jars from your classpath - mixing jars between versions is not supported!

Comment: @thomas Also note: please be careful about  getting into comment-question ping pong. 
And yes, that exception indicates a version mismatch of some sort.